# Will J2ME Location Based API work without GPS 

Tags: java, java-me, geolocation, location

Will J2ME Location Based API work without GPS?can you gave me example ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on the device implementation!

On many devices you can specify the behaviour during accessing the Location API. (Nokia s40 lets you search for bluetooth gps devices e.g.)

If the location API is able to use data like cellID, LAC, ... (if you specify low accuracy criteria) depends on the device implementation and even if your operator lets you use those values. ( http://www.easywms.com/easywms/?q=en/node/3589 )

Many devices do have the API on board even if they are not equipped with gps functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it will work, but it will be less accurate because it has to use the cell towers to determine location, not GPS.

Comment: Will this work? : http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/developing-location-based-services-introducing-location-api-j2me

Comment: More like this: talks about CellId: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/adding-location-a-non-gps-phone-introducing-cellid

Answer (score 0):

Well, the call will work, but how will it know where you are?

See the [discussion at Oracle](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/location/), which says:

> "To discover the location of the
>   device, LBS must use real-time
>   positioning methods. Accuracy depends
>   on the method used."

Answer (score 0):

In the United States, to provide semi-accurate tracking data for the 911 emergency system, all phones must be able to be located within a few hundred feet.  It's done by triangulating distance from the nearest three or so towers.

GPS simply makes that (existing) data more accurate.